# How to update settings for a swift/xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to `Xcode` and `Swift`.   There is an apparently known problem in `Swift` Compilations that I am attempting to address via a recommended fix that is stated here https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-compilation-reaching-arg-max-limit-causing-xcode-build-failure/6494/14

> Xcode 11 beta 3 added a flag to use an unlimited number of Swift files. You have to add USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE to YES in Build Settings - User Defined section. But this only works if you use the New Build System.
>   Tested on a dummy project with 2000 files inside an extra long path and it's working.

I am uncertain how/where to add this `USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE` = `NO`  setting.  Here is my `.xcodeproject` directory

[image]

Which file should be updated to include the new setting?

**Update** After applying the accepted answer from @JawadAli the `Target|Build|User defined settings` are here:

[image]

Comment: Go to the build settings in your target, there you can set all kind of flags, paths, etc.

Comment: @koen  I am new to Xcode : where are the target build settings?  I do better with Menu selections and there is no `Build` or `Run` on the main menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcode11

-build setting

-user-defined

-add setting: USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE (by pressing + sign on top)

-setValue:NO

[image]

Comment: I need further help here: I do not recognize the dialog you are showing. How is it launched from Xcode?  I am more of a command line or menu person so the menu selections would help. If it's some button i will never find it without being pointed to it.

Comment: check the image now... it has more details for you

Comment: Thx!   How did you add those awesome graphics to your image?  You're using something (much) better than `Preview`!

Comment: no.. i am using Preview ... in preview .. Go to tools ... and then Annotate .. you will find different options there

Comment: How did you get the encircled numbers? Did you actually draw a circle first then a number inside it??

Comment: Yup ... you are right ... use Oval and the put text in oval